# RAID 1 with 2 drives of different size

Tags: raid

I have a 2TB drive that is almost full so I am going to buy a 12TB archive drive that will just be used to store old files that nobody uses anymore (but that we still have to keep for legal reasons) and keep using the 2TB drive as my main drive.

I was wondering: is it possible to partition the 12TB drive into 2 (a 2TB partition and a 10TB partition) and have the 2TB partition be in RAID1 with the 2TB drive?

I would like to be able to use the 10TB partition freely.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your RAID controller permits pass-through of the drives ("HBA mode"), then [ZFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS) could also be put to good use in this instance.  Create a partition on your 12TB drive that is identical in size to your existing 2TB partition, and create a mirrored zpool of those two partitions.  Then you can create a non-redundant zpool of the remaining 10TB partition, and still enjoy the convenience of snapshotting, block-chain verification, etc.

OTOH, if your RAID controller doesn't support pass-through, ZFS is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is indeed possible using software RAID such as mdadm. It lets you either partition per disk or per partition (which would be your case)

Answer (score -2):

Most RAID controllers will not allow you to use the remaining space on the larger drive. Even if it did, performance would severely decrease by creating two virtual drives out of one physical drive, since only one of the virtual drives can be accessed at a time.

Also, keep in mind that the performance of the RAID 1 array with mismatched drives will always be held back by having to wait for the slower of the two drives to complete every operation.

Another option would be creating a spanned volume combing both drives, but that would be specific to your RAID controller or operating system.

Comment: Down voted because some of the advice here is bad - particularly creating a spanned volume which has no redundancy and in fact increases risk if failure. Software RAID has no problem working on a partition level either, and performance is no worse then would be expected (and can often be tuned to be better then the naive case.)